# Unix/OS X command to list clients connected to network

Tags: macos, unix, networking, router

I know there is a command to list all the clients that are connected to the same network I'm connected to and get basic information (IP, MAC...)
I thought of writing it down the last time I used it but probably figured I'd remember it. Yeah, right.

Comment: This kind of (non-programming-related) question is better suited for superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for **rwho**?

Comment: rwho displays nothing on my mac even though I have several devices connected to the wifi network...

Comment: Huh! You've mean clients as devices. I thought you were talking about PEOPLE!.. If you are talking about devices tcpdump and wireshark are your friends.